# How to deserialise json without property identifiers?

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

Assume a string of serialised data, that is close to JSON, except it does not contain property identifiers. So instead of

```
{
    "data": "Click Here",
    "size": 36,
    "style": "bold",
    "name": "text1",
    "hOffset": 250,
    "vOffset": 100,
    "alignment": "center",
    "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
}
```

I only have

```
{"Click Here", 36, "bold", "text1", 250, 100, "center", "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"}
```

In this case, the property names don't matter. They can, for instance, be assigned later as `property1, property2`...

I failed to autogenerate the class, since this is not a valid JSON. **Is there a way to recognize the class even though?** ... And then to deserialise that JSON to an object of that class? I prefer c#-based advices.

In case it helps, I attach the piece I am dealing with.

```
[[[4477929,"McGuire \/ Dowdy","Pazo \/ Gabi",32,"2015-07-07T06:50:00.0000000",[[10439425,39]],"0","0",1,[0,0,"2015-07-07T06:49:47.2870000",0],0,"\/sports\/beach-volleyball\/gstaad-grand-slam-women",,,10447,2,3,0,171.182,0,0,"\/sports\/beach-volleyball\/gstaad-grand-slam-women\/20150707\/mcguire-dowdy-vs-pazo-gabi\/",,,"","",[[168,"2"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4477939,"Bonnerova \/ Hermannova","Turnerova \/ Tomasekova",32,"2015-07-07T06:55:00.0000000",[[10439444,39]],"0","0",1,[0,0,"2015-07-07T06:54:12.7370000",0],0,"\/sports\/beach-volleyball\/gstaad-grand-slam-women",,,10447,1,0,0,0,0,0,"\/sports\/beach-volleyball\/gstaad-grand-slam-women\/20150707\/bonnerova-hermannova-vs-turnerova-tomasekova\/",,,"","",[[168,"2"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4477959,"Rosko \/ Tadic","Take \/ Mizoe",32,"2015-07-07T07:00:00.0000000",[[10439482,39]],"0","0",1,[0,0,"2015-07-07T07:02:07.3000000",0],0,"\/sports\/beach-volleyball\/gstaad-grand-slam-women",,,10447,1,0,0,0,0,0,"\/sports\/beach-volleyball\/gstaad-grand-slam-women\/20150707\/rosko-tadic-vs-take-mizoe\/",,,"","",[[168,"2"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4477850,"CSB Blazers","EAC Generals",2,"2015-07-07T06:00:00.0000000",[[10439229,39]],"42","31",1,[-13,335,"2015-07-07T07:12:35.1870000",0],20,"\/sports\/basketball\/philippines-ncaa",,,23623,22,7,0,277.050728066826,0,0,"\/sports\/basketball\/philippines-ncaa\/20150707\/csb-blazers-vs-eac-generals\/",,,"","",[[102,"18"],[103,"7"],[104,"18"],[105,"20"],[106,"36"],[107,"27"],[110,"0"],[111,"0"],[168,"2"],[170,"0"],[171,"3"],[109,"4"],[115,"31"],[108,"6"],[114,"42"]],1,-1,-1,0,,0],[4477871,"Valeriya Strakhova","Daniela Farfan",6,"2015-07-07T06:00:00.0000000",[[10439287,39]],"23402","36151",1,[0,1,"2015-07-07T06:06:19.6200000",0],0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments",,,12403,1,4,0,208.003,0,0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments\/20150707\/valeriya-strakhova-vs-daniela-farfan\/",,,"","",[[168,"2"],[172,"0"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4477895,"Laurynas Grigelis","Nicolae Frunza",6,"2015-07-07T06:35:00.0000000",[[10439370,39]],"4001","2002",1,[0,1,"2015-07-07T06:36:14.3870000",0],6,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments",,,12403,4,1,0,5.94447577285767,0,0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments\/20150707\/laurynas-grigelis-vs-nicolae-frunza\/",,,"","",[[168,"2"],[172,"0"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4477899,"Valeria Prosperi","Polina Novikova",6,"2015-07-07T06:35:00.0000000",[[10439375,39]],"5302","3001",1,[0,1,"2015-07-07T06:37:04.6830000",0],0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments",,,12403,1,1,0,3.8042,0,0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments\/20150707\/valeria-prosperi-vs-polina-novikova\/",,,"","",[[168,"2"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4477901,"Amina Anshba","Tamari Sumbadze",6,"2015-07-07T06:35:00.0000000",[[10439378,39]],"36152","1001",1,[0,1,"2015-07-07T06:37:35.4700000",0],0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments",,,12403,1,0,0,0,0,0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments\/20150707\/amina-anshba-vs-tamari-sumbadze\/",,,"","",[[168,"2"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4477903,"Anastasia Chikalkina","Aminat Kushkhova",6,"2015-07-07T06:35:00.0000000",[[10439381,39]],"3151","5002",1,[0,1,"2015-07-07T06:37:54.4900000",0],0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments",,,12403,1,0,0,0,0,0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments\/20150707\/anastasia-chikalkina-vs-aminat-kushkhova\/",,,"","",[[168,"2"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4477905,"Matias Zukas","Razvan Bobleaga",6,"2015-07-07T06:07:00.0000000",[[10439385,39]],"5001","2002",1,[0,0,"2015-07-07T06:39:02.4470000",0],6,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments",,,12403,4,1,0,3.8042,0,0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments\/20150707\/matias-zukas-vs-razvan-bobleaga\/",,,"","",[[168,"2"],[172,"0"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4477961,"Momkoonthod \/ Plipuech","Han \/ Kato",6,"2015-07-07T07:00:00.0000000",[[10439485,39]],"152","2001",1,[0,1,"2015-07-07T07:05:55.4500000",0],0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments",,,12403,1,0,0,0,0,0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments\/20150707\/momkoonthod-plipuech-vs-han-kato\/",,,"","",[[168,"2"],[172,"1"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4477963,"Lennart Zynga","Florian Lakat",6,"2015-07-07T07:00:00.0000000",[[10439488,39]],"301","2",1,[0,1,"2015-07-07T07:06:32.1800000",0],6,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments",,,12403,4,0,0,0,0,0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments\/20150707\/lennart-zynga-vs-florian-lakat\/",,,"","",[[168,"2"],[172,"2"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4477965,"Daniiar Duldaev","Mirko Cutuli",6,"2015-07-07T07:00:00.0000000",[[10439495,39]],"401","1152",1,[0,0,"2015-07-07T07:07:06.6300000",0],0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments",,,12403,1,0,0,0,0,0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments\/20150707\/daniiar-duldaev-vs-mirko-cutuli\/",,,"","",[[168,"2"],[172,"4"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4477967,"Barkin Yalcinkale","Ilya Ivashka",6,"2015-07-07T07:00:00.0000000",[[10439498,39]],"2","1001",1,[0,1,"2015-07-07T07:07:34.3700000",0],6,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments",,,12403,4,0,0,0,0,0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments\/20150707\/barkin-yalcinkale-vs-ilya-ivashka\/",,,"","",[[168,"2"],[172,"0"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4476418,"Ching-Wen Hsu [TPE]","Ling Zhang [HKG]",6,"2015-07-07T05:05:00.0000000",[[10437440,39]],"5002","7001",1,[0,1,"2015-07-06T19:39:52.6800000",0],0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-women-bangkok",,,21116,1,2,0,10.715806559515,0,0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-women-bangkok\/20150707\/ching-wen-hsu-vs-ling-zhang-\/",,,"","",[[172,"0"],[168,"2"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4476424,"Nagi Hanatani [JPN]","Nudnida Luangnam [THA]",6,"2015-07-07T05:05:00.0000000",[[10438853,39]],"151","152",1,[0,0,"2015-07-07T03:14:17.2400000",0],0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-women-bangkok",,,21116,1,1,0,3.10875,0,0,"\/sports\/tennis\/itf-women-bangkok\/20150707\/nagi-hanatani-vs-nudnida-luangnam-\/",,,"","",[[168,"2"],[172,"2"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4477947,"China Uni [W]","Czech Rep Uni [W]",10,"2015-07-07T07:00:00.0000000",[[10439454,39]],"5","5",1,[1,61,"2015-07-07T07:01:44.0130000",0],7,"\/sports\/handball\/universiade-women",,,23738,12,1,0,3,0,0,"\/sports\/handball\/universiade-women\/20150707\/china-uni-vs-czech-rep-uni-\/",,,"","",[[168,"2"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4477951,"Slovakia Uni [W]","Russia Uni [W]",10,"2015-07-07T07:00:00.0000000",[[10439462,39]],"2","5",1,[1,61,"2015-07-07T07:00:56.0130000",0],7,"\/sports\/handball\/universiade-women",,,23738,11,0,0,0,0,0,"\/sports\/handball\/universiade-women\/20150707\/slovakia-uni-vs-russia-uni-\/",,,"","",[[168,"2"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4477955,"Uruguay Uni [W]","Brazil Uni [W]",10,"2015-07-07T07:00:00.0000000",[[10439470,39]],"2","5",1,[1,121,"2015-07-07T07:05:09.8530000",0],7,"\/sports\/handball\/universiade-women",,,23738,10,1,0,224,0,0,"\/sports\/handball\/universiade-women\/20150707\/uruguay-uni-vs-brazil-uni-\/",,,"","",[[168,"2"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4477863,"Switzerland Uni","Canada Uni",19,"2015-07-07T06:00:00.0000000",[[10439255,39]],"1","0",1,[0,0,"2015-07-07T06:03:14.3600000",0],7,"\/sports\/volleyball\/universiade-men",,,10409,7,3,0,225.6874,0,0,"\/sports\/volleyball\/universiade-men\/20150707\/switzerland-uni-vs-canada-uni\/",,,"","",[[130,"25"],[131,"16"],[140,"1"],[141,"0"],[168,"2"],[132,"23"],[164,"1"],[133,"22"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4475048,"Gabor Gerold","Ivan Juzbasic",26,"2015-07-07T06:30:00.0000000",[[10439446,39]],"0","0",1,[0,0,"2015-07-07T06:54:41.4230000",0],0,"\/sports\/table-tennis\/challenger-series",,,15363,1,2,0,8.5008,0,0,"\/sports\/table-tennis\/challenger-series\/20150707\/gabor-gerold-vs-ivan-juzbasic\/",,,"","",[[168,"2"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4467339,"Sri Lanka [3rd Test]","Pakistan [3rd Test]",59,"2015-07-07T04:30:00.0000000",[[10413111,39]],"278 & 313","215 & 321\/3",1,[0,0,"2015-07-03T03:12:55.2830000",0],0,"\/sports\/cricket\/test-matches",,,19162,1,15,0,180.3224951318,0,0,"\/sports\/cricket\/test-matches\/20150707\/sri-lanka-vs-pakistan-\/",,,"","",[[165,"278 & 313"],[166,"215 & 321\/3"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0],[4477920,"Bangladesh","South Africa",59,"2015-07-07T06:45:00.0000000",[[10439403,39]],"0","29\/0",1,[0,0,"2015-07-07T06:43:45.6370000",0],0,"\/sports\/cricket\/twenty20-international",,,21809,1,4,0,1447.524,0,0,"\/sports\/cricket\/twenty20-international\/20150707\/bangladesh-vs-south-africa\/",,,"","",[[168,"2"],[165,"0"],[167,"1"],[166,"29\/0"]],0,-1,-1,0,,0]],[[32,"Beach Volleyball",32,"beach-volleyball",["Winner","Spread","Over\/Under"],0,0,"\/sports\/beach-volleyball\/",[]],[2,"Basketball",2,"basketball",["Moneyline","Spread","Over\/Under"],0,0,"\/sports\/basketball\/",[]],[6,"Tennis",6,"tennis",["Winner","Handicap","Over\/Under"],0,0,"\/sports\/tennis\/",[]],[10,"Handball",10,"handball",["1x2","Spread","Over\/Under"],0,0,"\/sports\/handball\/",[]],[19,"Volleyball",19,"volleyball",["Winner","Sets Handicap","Over\/Under"],0,0,"\/sports\/volleyball\/",[]],[26,"Table Tennis",26,"table-tennis",["MoneyLine","Spread","Over\/Under"],0,0,"\/sports\/table-tennis\/",[]],[59,"Cricket",59,"cricket",["MoneyLine","Spread","Over\/Under"],0,0,"\/sports\/cricket\/",[]]],[[10447,"Gstaad Grand Slam Women",0,700,0,,0,,32,"International",245,"ZZ","\/sports\/beach-volleyball\/gstaad-grand-slam-women\/"],[23623,"Philippines NCAA",0,190,0,,0,,2,"Philippines",173,"PH","\/sports\/basketball\/philippines-ncaa\/"],[12403,"ITF Tournaments",0,1192,0,,0,,6,"International",245,"ZZ","\/sports\/tennis\/itf-tournaments\/"],[21116,"ITF Women Bangkok",0,1233,0,,0,,6,"Thailand",211,"TH","\/sports\/tennis\/itf-women-bangkok\/"],[23738,"Universiade Women",0,1064,0,,0,,10,"International",245,"ZZ","\/sports\/handball\/universiade-women\/"],[10409,"Universiade Men",0,924,0,,0,,19,"International",245,"ZZ","\/sports\/volleyball\/universiade-men\/"],[15363,"Challenger Series",0,640,0,,0,,26,"Europe",256,"EU","\/sports\/table-tennis\/challenger-series\/"],[19162,"Test Matches",0,509,0,,0,,59,"International",245,"ZZ","\/sports\/cricket\/test-matches\/"],[21809,"Twenty20 International",0,661,0,,0,,59,"International",245,"ZZ","\/sports\/cricket\/twenty20-international\/"]],[]]
```

Comment: Without the property identifiers you're essentially reduced to some sort of CSV file format where the "columns" are known in advance. It would be possible to use this sort of format only if you controlled both the sender and receiver of the message so you could know what order the columns would be in. Otherwise it's going to be very fragile!

Comment: Perhaps take a look at the FileHelpers libarary: http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try transforming this into a JSON object with a single property that is an array. A quick look at it doesn't show anything weird, so the simplest thing you can try would be something like:

```
string data = "[...]"; // your sample data above
string jsonData = "{'data':" + data + "}";
```

and then try running the JSON parser on `jsonData`. That still doesn't solve the problem that these are some sort of records, but nothing guarantees you they all have the same structure, nor it helps you with the meaning of that data, but at least should give you a simple way to iterate over the data.

Note that you will likely need to do an additional transformation, as I noticed there are quite a few `,,` sequences, which depending on the JSON parser might throw an error or be considered as empty element. (And I don't remember if the standard allows it) To be on the safe side though, I'd suggest you do quick find and replace of `,,` to something like `,{},` (empty JSON object), `,"null",` (a well-known string that will never show in regular data), or something else that you can easily recognize.